# JBoss AS 7 Restful Webservices not auto deploying

Tags: jboss7.x, resteasy

I'm trying to use the built in Restful WebServices with JBoss AS 7. My web.xml is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       version="2.5">

</web-app>
```

My application class is...

```
package com.robert;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/services")

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public HelloWorld() {
    singletons.add(new Library());
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(Library.class);
    return classes;    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
```

}

and my class is

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/library")
public class Library {

@GET
@Path("/books")
public String getBooks() {
    return "this is all your books";
}

@GET
@Path("/book/{isbn}")
public String getBook(@PathParam("isbn") String id) {
    // search my database and get a string representation and return it
    return "Its a good book; I read it";
}

@PUT
@Path("/book/{isbn}")
public void addBook(@PathParam("isbn") String id, @QueryParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("Adding book "+name);
}

@DELETE
@Path("/book/{id}")
public void removeBook(@PathParam("id") String id ){
    System.out.println("Removing book "+id);

}
```

}

However, when I start JBoss AS7 the WebService is never started. I don't see it int he JBoss Management page and I don't see it at

```
http://foobar:8080/MyWar/services/library/books
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I discovered the problem. Following the directions from RestEasy I had installed the latest version of RestEasy into the JBoss module. When I reverted back to the default installation it work. Note that the web.xml *MUST NOT* contain any reference to the Restful servlets as the JBoss deployer auto deploys RestEasy when it sees the @ApplicationPath annotation on a class.
Web.xml should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add REST servlet mapping

in **web.xml** you need to add a servlet mapping to REST Servlet, something like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

where the URL pattern should match whatever is supposed to be handled as RESTFUL (or use /* - this will make your Rest servlet handle all requests to this application)

i dont know why but i have **never seen** any of my **Restful** web services in the Web Service Section on the JBoss management console but i see my WSDL SOAP based web services in that list.

However i do see the Restful projects in the manage deployments section of the Management console

Comment: But the entire point of the JBoss deployers is that it reflects across the classes in your WAR looking for the @Application annotation and adds the buildin RestEasy libraries.

Comment: Hmmm, I get an error because javax.ws.rs.core.Application is not a Servlet... ` exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.ws.rs.core.Application cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet`

Answer (score 0):

To fix your app:

1. Use `<web-app version="3.0" ..`
2. Add servlet mapping as in @austin's answer
3. Optionally, read section `2.3.2 Servlet` of jax-rs-1.1 [specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311), which will help you setup the rest of `web.xml`, though it's redundant in your example.

Also you may use [helloworld-rs](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/) quickstart accompanying jbossas-7 as a starting point to JavaEE 6 RESTful webapp.