# Using web.xml to configure JX-RS with Glassfish 4 is causing errors

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, web.xml, glassfish-4

I am trying to create a Java EE application utilizing JX-RS. I have got it working using the following configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("rs")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        // register root resource
        classes.add(ProbeREST.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

However, I would much prefer to use web.xml for the configuration. I think the above is very ugly in comparison to a simple xml configuration, like so:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to deploy the application, I receive the error:

```
Exception while deploying the app [my_app] : There is no web component by the name of javax.ws.rs.core.Application here.
```

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 5):

As described in JAX-RS 2.0, chapter *2.3.2 Servlet*, you do miss the ***servlet*** entry in your web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `servlet-mapping` in your `web.xml` is the problem, just remove it. It is not needed because you are deploying to a Servlet 3 compatible container, which supports automatic application registration without `web.xml`.

It should be sufficient if you `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

**See also:**

- [How to set up JAX-RS Application using annotations only (no web.xml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml)
- [How to deploy a JAX-RS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072295/how-to-deploy-a-jax-rs-application)
- [How to implement jaxrs Application without web.xml [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375831/how-to-implement-jaxrs-application-without-web-xml)